# Last page not rotated when using longtable and (pdf)lscape

Tags: longtable, pdflscape, lscape

I have a very long table (multiple pages) in a paper that I'm writing, which contains +20 tables. The problem occurs when I use both `landscape` and `longtable` together - namely, the last page of the table is no longer landscape but portrait, so half of the data is cut off. I have tried using both `lscape` and `pdflscape` and neither make much of a difference. At the bottom is a screenshot of what I see between the last and second-to-last pages.

Additionally, there is an extra blank page at the beginning of the table and I do not see a table header at the top, for example "Table 1." I'm using TeXShop 3.58 on a Mac. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint,revtex4]{emulateapj}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\tiny  
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable} {|p{2.0cm}|p{4.0cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.0cm}|}
\hline
\bf{Stuff 1} & \bf{Stuff 2} & \bf{Stuff 3} & \bf{Stuff 4} & \bf{Stuff 5} &     \bf{Stuff 6} & \bf{Stuff 7} & \bf{Stuff 8} & \bf{Stuff 9} & \bf{Stuff 10}  & \bf{Stuff 11}\\
\hline
\hline
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add \clearpage before \end{landscape}

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks! That helped with the rotation issue. However, I'm still not seeing the table header and there is an extra blank page at the top. Any thoughts?

Comment: Add \endhead at the end of the part to be repeated.  It wouldn't hurt to read the manual.  It should have been downloaded with the package, somewhere.

Comment: also don't put `longtable` in a `center` environment, it has no effect on its horizontal alignment, just adds spurious vertical space

Comment: @JohnKormylo that shouldn't be needed though (the definition of `\end[landscape}` already starts with `\clearpage`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You were correct - so much spurious vertical space that it was the cause for the extra blank page at the top. Thank you both for your help.